# python - understand correlation values between multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, correlation

i have tried to calculate the correlation between 10 features for 10 patients and i cannot understand the results or the graph plotted.

this is a sample of the correlation values:

> 1.0,0.8128622719957005,-0.2830993367981093,-0.3844193720183476,-0.41238582812051156,-0.7497467523764647,-0.7217849053670129,-0.23309094636132704,0.15518604621542448,-0.2320225569088316
>   0.8128622719957005,1.0,-0.3493873017039933,-0.4818571228874694,-0.5154234772968076,-0.7788765122708261,-0.8132521743513784,-0.6157319057842581,0.42812044824609996,-0.30990561312824777

[and this is the plotted graph of all 10 features for the 10 patients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10H4R.png)

can anyone help describing the output values and the graph?

Comment: Red cells in the plot mean there is high positive correlation between the variables, blue cells mean there is high negative correlation between the variables. For example, there is negative correlation between cadence and stride regularity, roughly meaning that when one goes up, the other goes down and vice-versa. Note how each variable is highly correlated with itself (intense red on the matrix diagonal).

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this link for your understanding. https://www.displayr.com/what-is-correlation/

As your sample values shows that there is positive and negative correlation between the variables.

## A correlation of 1 indicates a perfect positive correlation.

## A correlation of -1 indicates a perfect negative correlation.

## A correlation of 0 indicates that there is no relationship between the different variables.

Whereas for correlation value ranges from -1 to 1 you can refer the link i mentioned.
Now, for the feature selection or modelling phase you can select either strongly positive
correlated features or else strongly negative correlated features.
As the graph is plotted between -1 and 1 all values according with there values are plotted there .